# Our planet is capitalized!

Tags: discussion

Mars. Venus. Saturn. *Earth.*

We are a group of worldbuilders. We should be able to spell our planet’s name right.

In case you’re wondering, yes, I am stuck in bed sick on Christmas with nothing better to do than complain about the capitalization of our planet in multiple questions. Anyone who doesn’t like it should *find a cure for viruses*! (Please.)

Comment: [You need Jesus](https://youtu.be/J7fAE2epAoA?t=12)

Comment: @Mephistopheles Whoa. I could get behind a guy like that. I am curious... who is the guy beside him wearing the robe?

Comment: I fully agree with this message. The name of our planet is a *name* and names are capitalised. It's called Earth. It does also annoy me when it's spelled "earth" - no, that's just soil, not the planet. Also something that annoys me - "humans" are lowercase because that's not a name, nor something we capitalise. By extension, other races such as elves, dwarves, dragons, gnomes, etc. also start with a lowercase.

Comment: I have found a kindred spirit in @VLAZ. If you are ever royally sick on a holiday, check with me... we can pass the time mocking those who put capital E on “elf”. BUT I hope you’re ok with my long-term campaign to convince everyone put the period outside the quote marks except when it’s part of the actual quote. Otherwise, it’ll be a long holiday... the bad kind. :-)

Comment: Best thing you can do, whislt sick in bed, is to make it your project to edit as many instances of the name Earth as you can find!

I've often made that edit (and Moon as well).

Comment: As best I follow current usage, "the planet Earth" is capitalized, but in the general sense of "the world" - as in "how on earth do I...?" it is not. And on no circumstances is earth meaning "soil, dirt, land" to be capitalized. (I'm bang alongside you on the logical quotes, though.)

Comment: @James Standards for the site are perfectly valid meta posts.